# R: How to use summarize and do function together on grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In tidyverse, summarise can be used on grouped data with single valued functions. For example

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(max(cos(mpg)))
```

If the function is vector-valued then, if I am not wrong, it's recommended to use do. For example, the do command works for the vector valued function 'describe' from phych package:

```
 library(psych)
 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(describe(.$mpg))
```

How to apply both a single-valued and a vector-valued functions to grouped data at the same time? For example, how to apply both max(cos()) and describe() to mpg column, and have the output as one dataframe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can place the output of `describe` in a `list` within the `summarise` and then `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(Cosmpg = max(cos(mpg)), list(describe(mpg))) %>%
    unnest
# A tibble: 3 x 15
#    cyl Cosmpg  vars     n  mean    sd median trimmed   mad   min   max range   skew kurtosis    se
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1  4.00  0.743  1.00 11.0   26.7  4.51   26.0    26.4  6.52  21.4  33.9 12.5   0.259   -1.65  1.36 
#2  6.00  0.939  1.00  7.00  19.7  1.45   19.7    19.7  1.93  17.8  21.4  3.60 -0.158   -1.91  0.549
#3  8.00  0.989  1.00 14.0   15.1  2.56   15.2    15.2  1.56  10.4  19.2  8.80 -0.363   -0.566 0.684
```

Comment: As always, your answers are amazingly elegant @akrun! No need to use do, just list within summarise and then unnest.